# Custom CNG KSP and Logon domain

Tags: cryptography, kerberos, winlogon

I'm implementing the program related to logon domain with certificate by custom KSP and my credential provider. I have successfully interacted from my credential provider to custom KSP. I'm in the process of implementing custom KSP. The steps I perform handling in custom KSP are as follows:

1. Install the template certificate Kerberos that has been issued from ADCS to local machine store. [This is step](https://github.com/sliva1994/KSP-Custom/blob/master/PreparationStepsADSever_ClientWindow.pdf)  how I Issue certificates and set up logons. **Is there something missing**?
2. Export the private key from the file (.pfx) that has been issued from ADCS via the command.

> ```
>     #openssl pkcs12 -in sample.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out sample.key.
>     #openssl rsa -in sample.key -out sample_private.key.
> ```

3. The flow custom KSP looks like this:

> *SampleKSPOpenProvider() -> SampleKSPOpenKey()->*
> *SampleKSPGetKeyProperty() -> SampleKSPSignHash()*

3. *At SampleKSPSignHash()*, My signing data is a buffer that contains the encoded certificate ( [pbCertEncoded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-cert_context)) and I signed the certificate with the private key and also verified the signature with the public key successfully.
   I think the final handling is always in the *SampleKSPSignHash ()* function, and I know that function can be called multiple times so I tried force code to always return the **pbSignature** signature,  but still could not logon the domain.The event log always returns the error code **ID 4625**. About CAPI2 and Crypto-NCrypt log, Although I have enabled but when deploy logon with  custom KSP and my credential provider doesn't output. It seems that has not been called yet, then I tried to logon with the default password window, the log was exported. Currently I only have a  [Log in Custom KSP](https://github.com/sliva1994/KSP-Custom/blob/master/Log.txt) developing. **Is code handling logic wrong?**

   Below is the code of *SampleKSPSignHash()*:

   ```
   SECURITY_STATUS WINAPI SampleKSPSignHash(
    __in    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProvider,
    __in    NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey,
    __in_opt    VOID* pPaddingInfo,
    __in_bcount(cbHashValue) PBYTE pbHashValue,
    __in    DWORD   cbHashValue,
    __out_bcount_part_opt(cbSignaturee, *pcbResult) PBYTE pbSignature,
    __in    DWORD   cbSignaturee,
    __out   DWORD* pcbResult,
    __in    DWORD   dwFlags)
    {
        SECURITY_STATUS     Status = NTE_INTERNAL_ERROR;
        NTSTATUS            ntStatus = STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR;
        SAMPLEKSP_KEY* pKey = NULL;
        DWORD               cbTmpSig = 0;
        DWORD               cbTmp = 0;
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hProvider);
        DebugPrint("Call function ");

        //Start workround
        //Add handling to hash data and sign certificate with private key.
        char text[4096];
        DWORD dwBufferLen = 0, cbKeyBlob = 0;
        PBYTE pbBuffer = NULL, pbKeyBlob = NULL;
        LPBYTE   lpHashData;
        DWORD    dwHashDataSize;
        NTSTATUS status;
        BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE  hAlg;
        DWORD    dwSignatureSize;
        PBYTE   lpSignature;
        BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO padding_PKCS1;
        padding_PKCS1.pszAlgId = BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM;

        //Start Regardless of which calls to take, force always signs with the current certificate
        //Alway force input pbHashValue = aCertContext->pbCertEncoded
        HCERTSTORE hMyCertStore = NULL;
        PCCERT_CONTEXT aCertContext = NULL;
        LPBYTE pbData = NULL;
        DWORD cbData = 0;
        DWORD dwKeySpec;
        hMyCertStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        L"MY");

        if (hMyCertStore == NULL)
        {
            DebugPrint("Call function -> hMyCertStore is NULL");
        }
        aCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hMyCertStore,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR_A,
        L"test01", // use appropriate subject name
        NULL);
        if (aCertContext == NULL)
        {
            DebugPrint("Call function -> Error: aCertContext is NULL");
        }

        pbHashValue = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, aCertContext->cbCertEncoded);
        CopyMemory(pbHashValue, aCertContext->pbCertEncoded, aCertContext->cbCertEncoded);
        cbHashValue = aCertContext->cbCertEncoded;
        // End force

        //Debug printout
        DebugPrint("Call function - cbHashValue= %ld", cbHashValue);
        DebugPrint("Call function - cbSignaturee= %ld", cbSignaturee);
        DebugPrint("Call function - dwFlags= %ld", dwFlags);
        for (int i = 0; i < cbHashValue; i++)
        {
            sprintf((char*)text + (i * 2), "%02X", pbHashValue[i]);
        }
        DebugPrint("Call function -> pbHashValue: %s", text);

        // ------- HARCODE PRIVATE KEY ------ //
        //Import the previously exported private key using the pfx file.Use the command below to     
        //export the private key.
        //Command :#openssl pkcs12 -in sample.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out sample.key
        //         #openssl rsa -in sample.key -out sample_private.key
        const char* szPemPrivKeyPass =
        "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
        "MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA1MtKkDL5RuY7lYwCZy38x1w9kisJLhyb7VkIlodJPLyqkQUZ"
        "eDjEvSyKl75ucgB4gzyO4MyYbH/lrttXH2sR830gG40MKz6EnsxyzCsCgYEA4AUC"
        "fz5l+q7lW9Fm+hhM9duDFO5EME6RDJp6MIEWH9C0khv2wWhNJCdWNPwwlPgCWIpL"
        "7ueaVfhErJkJLzH8V8gIPpb5Hot4YUycTNvZffSeS+RE5AF9kWgzlxcd31fGHgZZ"
        "f9W0xn7ieQS3fFnVWlK900drOQ+qkQ8jMKvxDdcCgYEAtUJnGoSFq6undecimpVI"
        "qwzzfr+MKpt7Ym+cdDrJ3qts+kYCD35O80lNM6TqqSJqCB76EwV3VmyzKQ+1/bZ9"
        "wrb2FPOTew+ytzDh20dOHpAaVt3krCRQ4gBWzjgsWq4NP5cQParfSbvYBlBTkcJX"
        "........................................................."
        "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

        DebugPrint("Process Start import private key");
        if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(szPemPrivKeyPass, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, NULL, &dwBufferLen, 
        NULL, NULL))
        {
            DebugPrint("Failed to convert BASE64 private key. Error 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
        }
        pbBuffer = (PBYTE)LocalAlloc(0, dwBufferLen);
        if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(szPemPrivKeyPass, 0, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, pbBuffer, 
        &dwBufferLen, NULL, NULL))
        {
            DebugPrint("Failed to convert BASE64 private key. Error 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
        }
        if (!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, 
        pbBuffer, dwBufferLen, 0, NULL, NULL, &cbKeyBlob))
        {
            DebugPrint("Failed to parse private key. Error 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
        }
        pbKeyBlob = (PBYTE)LocalAlloc(0, cbKeyBlob);
        if (!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, 
        pbBuffer, 
        dwBufferLen, 0, NULL, pbKeyBlob, &cbKeyBlob))
        {
            DebugPrint("Failed to parse private key. Error 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
        }

        // ---------START  HASH DATA ------------//
        DebugPrint("Start Hash the data");
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider");
            return 0;
        }

        //Import key pair
        status = BCryptImportKeyPair(hAlg, NULL, LEGACY_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, &hKey, (PUCHAR)pbKeyBlob, 
        cbKeyBlob, 0);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: BCryptImportKeyPair : 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Hash Data certificate 
        if (!GetHashData((LPBYTE)pbHashValue, cbHashValue, &lpHashData, &dwHashDataSize)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: GetHashData");
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Sign hash certificate
        BCryptSignHash(hKey, &padding_PKCS1, (LPBYTE)lpHashData, dwHashDataSize, NULL, 0,    
        &dwSignatureSize, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);

        pbSignature = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, dwSignatureSize);
        status = BCryptSignHash(hKey, &padding_PKCS1, (LPBYTE)lpHashData, dwHashDataSize, 
        pbSignature, dwSignatureSize, pcbResult, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);

        //Debug print 
        DebugPrint("Call function - dwHashDataSize= %ld", dwHashDataSize);
        DebugPrint("Call function - pcbResult= %ld", *pcbResult);
        DebugPrint("Call function - dwSignatureSize= %ld", dwSignatureSize);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: BCryptSignHash= %X", status);
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpHashData);
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbSignature);
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Print the Signature data.
        char textPn[4096];
        for (int i = 0; i < dwSignatureSize; i++){
            sprintf((char*)textPn + (i * 2), "%02X", pbSignature[i]);
        }
        DebugPrint("pbSignature: %s", textPn);

        // Verify the signature with the public key
        if (!VerifySign(pbSignature, dwSignatureSize)) {
            DebugPrint("Error signature");
            return FALSE;
        }

        DebugPrint("Verify the signature success", );
        Status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
        //End workround

        cleanup:
            return Status;
        }

    BOOL VerifySign(
    __in_bcount(cbSignaturee) PBYTE pbSignature,
    __in    DWORD   cbSignaturee)
    {
        HCERTSTORE hMyCertStore = NULL;
        PCCERT_CONTEXT aCertContext = NULL;
        LPBYTE pbData = NULL;
        DWORD cbData = 0;
        DWORD dwKeySpec;
        PBYTE pbOutput = NULL;
        PBYTE   vHashData;
        DWORD   vHashDataSize;
        NTSTATUS status;
        BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO padding_PKCS1;
        padding_PKCS1.pszAlgId = BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM;

        DebugPrint("Start VerifySign");
        hMyCertStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        L"MY");

        if (hMyCertStore == NULL)
        {
            DebugPrint("Call function -> hMyCertStore is NULL");
            return FALSE;
        }
        aCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hMyCertStore,
        X509_ASN_ENCODING,
        0,
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR_A,
        L"test01", // use appropriate subject name 
        NULL
        );

        if (aCertContext == NULL)
        {
            DebugPrint("Call function -> Error: aCertContext is NULL");
            return FALSE;
        }

        PCCERT_CONTEXT pcCertContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING, aCertContext- 
        >pbCertEncoded, aCertContext->cbCertEncoded);

        if (!pcCertContext)
        {
            DebugPrint("ERROR: pcCertContext");
            return FALSE;
        }
        BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE publicKeyHandle = NULL;
        if (!CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2(X509_ASN_ENCODING, &pcCertContext->pCertInfo- 
        >SubjectPublicKeyInfo, 0, NULL, &publicKeyHandle))
        {
            DebugPrint("CryptImportPublicKeyInfoEx2 failed");
            return FALSE;
        }

        pbOutput = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, aCertContext->cbCertEncoded);
        CopyMemory(pbOutput, aCertContext->pbCertEncoded, aCertContext->cbCertEncoded);

        if (!GetHashData((LPBYTE)pbOutput, aCertContext->cbCertEncoded, &vHashData, &vHashDataSize))         
        {
            DebugPrint("GetHashData failed.");
            return FALSE;
        }

        status = BCryptVerifySignature(publicKeyHandle, &padding_PKCS1, vHashData, vHashDataSize, 
        pbSignature, cbSignaturee, BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: BCryptSignHash= %X", status);
            return FALSE;
        }
            DebugPrint("Verify Sign OK");
            return TRUE;
        }

    BOOL GetHashData(PBYTE lpData, DWORD dwDataSize, PBYTE* lplpHashData, LPDWORD lpdwHashDataSize)
    {
        BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE  hAlg;
        BCRYPT_HASH_HANDLE hHash;
        DWORD              dwResult;
        DWORD              dwHashObjectSize;
        PBYTE             lpHashObject;
        NTSTATUS           status;

        DebugPrint("Call function ");
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        DebugPrint("Call function ");
        BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&dwHashObjectSize, sizeof(DWORD), 
        &dwResult, 0);

        lpHashObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, dwHashObjectSize);
        status = BCryptCreateHash(hAlg, &hHash, lpHashObject, dwHashObjectSize, NULL, 0, 0);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DebugPrint("Error: BCryptCreateHash 0x%.8X\n", GetLastError());
            DebugPrint("Error: status= %X\n", status);
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpHashObject);
            BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
            return FALSE;
        }

        DebugPrint("Call function ");
        BCryptHashData(hHash, lpData, dwDataSize, 0);
        BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH, (PBYTE)lpdwHashDataSize, sizeof(DWORD), 
        &dwResult,0);
        *lplpHashData = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, *lpdwHashDataSize);
        BCryptFinishHash(hHash, *lplpHashData, *lpdwHashDataSize, 0);

        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpHashObject);
        BCryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
        DebugPrint("Call function ");
        return TRUE;
    }
   ```

I also wonder if this Issue has anything to do with the my **Credential Provider**?

Below is my current Credential Provider code:

```
   //Build the authentication data used by LsaLogonUser
   void ConstructAuthInfo(LPBYTE* ppbAuthInfo, ULONG* pulAuthInfoLen)
   {
       DebugPrint("call function");
       WCHAR szCardName[] = L""; 
       WCHAR szContainerName[] = L"";
       WCHAR szReaderName[] = L"";
       WCHAR szCspName[] = L"Microsoft Sample Key Storage Provider";
       WCHAR szPin[] = L"1234";
       ULONG ulPinByteLen = wcslen(szPin) * sizeof(WCHAR);
       WCHAR szUserName[] = L"test01";
       ULONG ulUserByteLen = wcslen(szUserName) * sizeof(WCHAR);
       WCHAR szDomainName[] = L"xyz.co"; 
       ULONG ulDomainByteLen = wcslen(szDomainName) * sizeof(WCHAR);
       LPBYTE pbAuthInfo = NULL;
       ULONG  ulAuthInfoLen = 0;
       KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON* pKerbCertLogon;
       KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO* pKerbCspInfo;
       LPBYTE pbDomainBuffer, pbUserBuffer, pbPinBuffer;
       LPBYTE pbCspData;
       LPBYTE pbCspDataContent;

       ULONG ulCspDataLen = sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) - 
       sizeof(TCHAR) + (wcslen(szCardName) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR) +
       (wcslen(szCspName) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR) +
       (wcslen(szContainerName) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR) +
       (wcslen(szReaderName) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

       ulAuthInfoLen = sizeof(KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON) +
       ulDomainByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR) + ulUserByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR) +
       ulPinByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR) + ulCspDataLen;

       pbAuthInfo = (LPBYTE)CoTaskMemAlloc(ulAuthInfoLen);
       ZeroMemory(pbAuthInfo, ulAuthInfoLen);

       pbDomainBuffer = pbAuthInfo + sizeof(KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON);
       pbUserBuffer = pbDomainBuffer + ulDomainByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR);
       pbPinBuffer = pbUserBuffer + ulUserByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR);
       pbCspData = pbPinBuffer + ulPinByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR);

       memcpy(pbDomainBuffer, szDomainName, ulDomainByteLen);
       memcpy(pbUserBuffer, szUserName, ulUserByteLen);
       memcpy(pbPinBuffer, szPin, ulPinByteLen);

       pKerbCertLogon = (KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON*)pbAuthInfo;

       pKerbCertLogon->MessageType = KerbCertificateLogon;
       pKerbCertLogon->DomainName.Length = (USHORT)ulDomainByteLen;
       pKerbCertLogon->DomainName.MaximumLength = (USHORT)(ulDomainByteLen 
       + sizeof(WCHAR));
       pKerbCertLogon->DomainName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbDomainBuffer - pbAuthInfo);
       pKerbCertLogon->UserName.Length = (USHORT)ulUserByteLen;
       pKerbCertLogon->UserName.MaximumLength = (USHORT)(ulUserByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR));
       pKerbCertLogon->UserName.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbUserBuffer - pbAuthInfo);
       pKerbCertLogon->Pin.Length = (USHORT)ulPinByteLen;
       pKerbCertLogon->Pin.MaximumLength = (USHORT)(ulPinByteLen + sizeof(WCHAR));
       pKerbCertLogon->Pin.Buffer = (PWSTR)(pbPinBuffer - pbAuthInfo);

       pKerbCertLogon->CspDataLength = ulCspDataLen;
       pKerbCertLogon->CspData = (PUCHAR)(pbCspData - pbAuthInfo);

       pKerbCspInfo = (KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO*)pbCspData;
       pKerbCspInfo->dwCspInfoLen = ulCspDataLen;
       pKerbCspInfo->MessageType = 1;
       pKerbCspInfo->KeySpec = CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_SPEC;
       //pKerbCspInfo->KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE;

       pKerbCspInfo->nCardNameOffset = 0;
       pKerbCspInfo->nReaderNameOffset = pKerbCspInfo->nCardNameOffset + wcslen(szCardName) + 1;
       pKerbCspInfo->nContainerNameOffset = pKerbCspInfo->nReaderNameOffset + wcslen(szReaderName) + 1;
       pKerbCspInfo->nCSPNameOffset = pKerbCspInfo->nContainerNameOffset + wcslen(szContainerName) + 1;

       pbCspDataContent = pbCspData + sizeof(KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO) - sizeof(TCHAR);
       memcpy(pbCspDataContent + (pKerbCspInfo->nCardNameOffset * sizeof(WCHAR)), szCardName, wcslen(szCardName) * sizeof(WCHAR));
       memcpy(pbCspDataContent + (pKerbCspInfo->nReaderNameOffset * sizeof(WCHAR)), szReaderName, wcslen(szReaderName) * sizeof(WCHAR));
       memcpy(pbCspDataContent + (pKerbCspInfo->nContainerNameOffset * sizeof(WCHAR)), szContainerName, wcslen(szContainerName) * sizeof(WCHAR));
       memcpy(pbCspDataContent + (pKerbCspInfo->nCSPNameOffset * sizeof(WCHAR)), szCspName, wcslen(szCspName) * sizeof(WCHAR));

       *ppbAuthInfo = pbAuthInfo;
       *pulAuthInfoLen = ulAuthInfoLen;
       DebugPrint("call function -> 12");
   }

   HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSerialization(
   _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE *pcpgsr,
   _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION *pcpcs,
   _Outptr_result_maybenull_ PWSTR *ppwszOptionalStatusText,
   _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon)
   {
       if (DEVELOPING) PrintLn("Credential::GetSerialization");
       HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
       *pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED;
       *ppwszOptionalStatusText = nullptr;
       *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_NONE;
       ZeroMemory(pcpcs, sizeof(*pcpcs));

       //Start add connect to KSP
       if (DEVELOPING) DebugPrint("Start test login");
       ULONG ulAuthPackage;
       hr = RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(&ulAuthPackage);
       ConstructAuthInfo(&pcpcs->rgbSerialization, &pcpcs->cbSerialization);

       if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
       {
            DebugPrint("Start test SUCCEEDED");
            pcpcs->ulAuthenticationPackage = ulAuthPackage;
    pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_CSample;

           *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
            DebugPrint("End test SUCCEEDED");
        }

       return hr;
   }

   HRESULT RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(ULONG* pulAuthPackage)
   {
       HRESULT hr = S_OK;
       HANDLE hLsa = NULL;

       NTSTATUS status = LsaConnectUntrusted(&hLsa);
       if (SUCCEEDED(HRESULT_FROM_NT(status)))
       {
           ULONG ulAuthPackage;
           LSA_STRING lsaszKerberosName;
           _LsaInitString(&lsaszKerberosName, MICROSOFT_KERBEROS_NAME_A);//NEGOSSP_NAME_A or MICROSOFT_KERBEROS_NAME_A
           status = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(hLsa, &lsaszKerberosName, &ulAuthPackage);
           if (SUCCEEDED(HRESULT_FROM_NT(status)))
           {
               *pulAuthPackage = ulAuthPackage;
               hr = S_OK;
           }
           else
           {
               hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);
           }
           LsaDeregisterLogonProcess(hLsa);
       }
       else
       {
           hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);
       }

       return hr;
   }
```

This is all my code [SampleKSP.c](https://github.com/sliva1994/KSP-Custom/blob/master/SampleKSP.c). Thank in advance.

Comment: 4635 is just the event id and not very helpful. Look at all the other data inside this event (Security ID, Account Name, Account Domain, Logon ID). Furthermore that shold be a status and a substatus as hexcode. These should give you a clearer idea what's wrong.

Comment: @Frank, I enabled the log on kerberos on the server side and it unexpectedly appeared. When the logon fails in addition to error code 4635 (on the client side) I also receive an Event ID 4768 (F) - Authentication Failure code, the result code (0x29 KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED) on the server side. - Log Details: https://github.com/sliva1994/KSP-Custom/blob/master/WindowsEventID_4768.png
- Thanks in advance

Comment: This could have a lot of reasons. You might have a lookk here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4768. BTW: If you show screenshots it would be better to set your machine language to english, most people here cannot read korean very well ;-)

Comment: Looking at the code above about signing a certificate with a private key and verifying the certificate with a public key, I am wondering if the processing logic is wrong? Can you give me an idea that you've done successfully before? (create, sign, and verify certificates) and implementation at KSP.- Thanks in advance

Comment: I can only tell you that we do all the signing outside in a hardware device and do not verify the signature in our code (only in unittests). The rest is a company secret, sorry.